# force browser to cache a MP4 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, articulate-storyline

I'm using *Articulate Storyline* to create a simple web app.

The app consists of 10 slides. I have an MP4 video on *slide 10*. The problem is I can't find a way to preload the video (which is on the last slide) when the user starts the first slide because it seems that Storyline puts each slide in the separate HTML pages or something like that.

Ofcourse we can access the video on each slide using the code below but only if the user is in that slide:

```
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
```

When I can't select the video on slide 10 from slide 1 then I can't preload it either.

Storyline stores the video in the story_content folder and I know the file name and the exact path of it.

Is there any possible way to force caching that specific MP4 file?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.